# Memory management for Objective-C properties without an iVar and with explicit setter and getter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am new to Cocoa development and was wondering how should memory be handled for a property without an iVar and with explicit setter and getter.

Here is what is looks like:

```
/////* - Interface- */
@interface MyCustomView: NSView {
  MyCustomButton *_button;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomButton *button; // normal property
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; // This is the one I am talking about

@end

/////*-Implmentation-*/
@implementation MyCustomView

@synthesize button = _button;

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title {
  [[self button] setTitle:title];
}

- (NSString *)title {
  return [[self button] title];
}


- (void)dealloc {
   [_button release];
   [super dealloc]
}
@end
```

How is memory for "title" handled in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

> How is memory for "title" handled in this case ?

There's nothing to handle. You're not creating or storying any objects, so there's nothing to worry about.

If you're using ARC (you should), the explicit `[_button release]` in your `-dealloc` method should go away.

Since you specify `copy` in your `title` property, you should make sure that the object that's passed in is copied. Most of the time it won't matter since you're probably using immutable strings which are never *really* copied anyway, but still...

```
`[[self button] setTitle:[title copy]];`
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It makes sense. The button is an NSButton.  I'll make sure that the title property on custom button is copy as well. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Curious1 It was the iOS tag that fooled me -- I've removed it.

Comment: Since it looks like you aren't using ARC, you would want to make sure to release the copy you make. `self.button.title = [[title copy] autorelease];` would work, as would `title = [title copy]; self.button.title = title; [title release];`.

Comment: Clarification: If you're using ARC, the entire dealloc method should go away.  You don't need to release _button, and you are not allowed to call [super dealloc] - your method would become empty.